# Resultado de Query com SET STATISTICS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Queria saber se tem como eu conseguir pegar o resultado do "SET STATISTICS TIME ON".
Por exemplo, o resultado da minha query deu 1139ms. Tem como eu pegar esse resultado e manipulá-lo?
Converter para segundos, minutos, gravar em uma tabela...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

não acredito que seja possivel, em todo caso você conseguirá o mesmo resultado ao manipular duas variaveis.

```
DECLARE @ExecInicio DATETIME2(7)
DECLARE @ExecTermino DATETIME2(7)

SET @ExecInicio = sysdatetime();

-- MinhaQuery

SET @ExecTermino = sysdatetime();

SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, @ExecInicio, @ExecTermino) -- segundos.
```